# numpy reshape based on index

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have an array:

```
arr = [
  ['00', '01', '02'],
  ['10', '11', '12'],
]
```

I want to reshape this array considering its indices:

```
reshaped = [
  [0, 0, '00'],
  [0, 1, '01'],
  [0, 2, '02'],
  [1, 0, '10'],
  [1, 1, '11'],
  [1, 2, '12'],
]
```

Is there a `numpy` or `pandas` way to do that? Or do I have to do the good old `for`?

```
for x, arr_x in enumerate(arr):
    for y, val in enumerate(arr_x):
        print(x, y, val)
```

Comment: Do you need to keep the mix of integers and strings?  A 'normal' numpy array will use one or the other, not the mix.  As shown you are using lists and list notation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `np.indices` to get the indices and then stitch everything together...

```
arr = np.array(arr)
i, j = np.indices(arr.shape)
np.concatenate([i.reshape(-1, 1), j.reshape(-1, 1), arr.reshape(-1, 1)], axis=1)
```

Comment: one-linerized `np.column_stack([*map(np.ravel, [*np.indices(np.shape(arr)), arr])])`

Answer (score 1):

I would use [numpy.ndenumerate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html) for that purpose, following way:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([['00', '01', '02'],['10', '11', '12']])
output = [[*inx,x] for inx,x in np.ndenumerate(arr)]
print(*output,sep='\n') # print sublists in separate lines to enhance readibility
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, '00']
[0, 1, '01']
[0, 2, '02']
[1, 0, '10']
[1, 1, '11']
[1, 2, '12']
```

As side note: this action is *not* reshaping, as reshaping mean movement of elements, as output contain more cells it is impossible to do it with just reshaping.

Comment: This still uses a for-loop though. Close but no cigar.